# Is nullable boolean (bool?) considered thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, nullable, atomic

As the title says, are nullable booleans (bool?) to be considered atomic in their read/write operations? I made a search through the C# documentation to no avail. I know for a fact that only certain primitive types guarantee atomicity in performing read/write operations, and Bool is one of these types. Of course nullable booleans are a different story; they're objects after all so I would say no but...can someone shed some light on this subject?

Answer (score 8):

C# does not guarantee that reads and writes of nullable variables are atomic. The types for which operations are guaranteed to be atomic are defined in section 5.5 of the specification (Atomicity of variable references):

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

Note that while nullables can be null, they are not reference types. They are value types that have special boxing behavior provided by the runtime. In the context of the specification, they are called nullable value types if they require special treatment.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Nullable(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: I assume the question is asking about reading/writing variables of type `bool?`, not operations on them.

Comment: This doesn't really address whether assignment to a nullable variable is atomic, though it does imply that reading Value or HasValue may not be thread-safe.  Things get a bit fuzzy, though, since nullables do have special runtime support.  It can be tricky to interpret that statement in the document, since it's somewhat of a 'catch-all' statement appended to the documentation of any class that wasn't designed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a `bool?` is actually a `Nullable<bool>` under the hood; in other words, it's a structure.  There are some special runtime features that make these behave as if they can be null for purposes of things like boxing, but ultimately it's a structure with a `HasValue` flag and the actual value.

Odds are quite good that this does not provide atomic read/write guarantees.  It could theoretically be accomplished for `bool?`, since you could fit all the necessary data into a single machine word, but not really possible for general nullable instances without baking in some synchronization around nullable access.

---

On a side note, if you need something like this, consider that a `bool?` is essentially just a tri-state value.  You can accomplish the same result with an Enum having three states, which does provide atomic read/write guarantees (as it's just an int under the hood, by default.)  Though, generally, it's much safer to just use synchronization primitives rather than trying to properly implement lock-free code.

Answer (score -1):

In theory: It's just like you said, there is no guarantee.

In practice: Copying it from one variable to another is threadsafe. Reading and writing it not neccesarily.

This means:

```
shared = true; //avoid this
bool result = shared.Value; //avoid this, too

bool? local = true;
shared = local; //threadsafe in practice
[...]
local = shared; //threadsafe in practice
```

Reason is, that pointer sized or smaller structs are copied as whole in one step by the runtime, if there is no type conversion going on.

Making the value useful requires two steps: 1. Check the flag if it is null 2. Read the actual content. That means it is probably not threadsafe.

You are probably better off using an `int` with constants for true, false and null. This also allows you to use the Interlocked functions (Exchange and CompareExchange can be very handy!)

Answer (score -1):

Giving my implementation of `Nullable<bool>` property:

```
// defaultValue: 0 = false, 1 = true, 2 = null
private int _threadSafeNullBool = 2;

public bool? ThreadSafeNullBool
{
    get
    {
        // check for value with noop (if value is 2, set to 2)
        switch (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 2, 2))
        {
            case 2:
                return null;
            case 1:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        // setting null
        if (!value.HasValue)
        {
            // if value is 0, set 2
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 2, 0) == 1) // if value is 1
            {
                // set 2
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 2);
            }
        }
        // setting true
        else if (value.Value)
        {
            // if value is 0, set 1
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 1, 0) == 2) // if value is 2
            {
                // set 1
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 1);
            }
        }
        // setting false
        else
        {
            // if value is 1, set 0
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 0, 1) == 2) // if value is 2
            {
                // set 0
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _threadSafeNullBool, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation:

I am using `_threadSafeNullBool` as backing field with 3 states (0 = false, 1 = true, 2 = null).

In the getter of the `Nullable<bool>` property I am simply getting the variable value and comparing it to the states and returing according value. I am using `Interlocked.CompareExchange` function as it reads the latest value of the variable (not the one cached by current thread).

In the setter there is similar code for every possible state. For setting `null` I am firstly using `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to set the variable to value `2` if the current value is `0` (third parameter of the method).
The method is returning original value (before possible setting it to `2`) and I am comparing this value with `1` (possible state, wich is not captured by `CompareExchange` itself). If the comparison succeeded (value was `1`) I am setting it to the value `2` with the method `Interlocked.Exchange`.

*Similar code is used for every possible state in `value`. Only the values are changed*.

Comment: What's the reasoning for doing an `Interlocked.CompareExchange` before every `Interlocked.Exchange`? Also if you are doing all this interlocked stuff just for ensuring the visibility of `_threadSafeNullBool`, couldn't you just define it as `volatile`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `_threadSafeNullBool` cannot be just defined volatile, as `Nullable<bool>` has not atomic read/write operations (unlike `bool`) - and I don't want to have `public int` variable with some magic constant values.
And simply setting it to `volatile` does not guerantee thread safety, as one of the accessing threads can get old value.
The `CompareExchange` in the first case (setting null) is setting value `2` into the variable only when the previous value was `0`, so then i am comparing it to possible value `1` and setting it to `2` afterwards if it matches.

Comment: AFAICS the `_threadSafeNullBool` is not `Nullable<bool>`, it is `int`, so its reads/writes should be atomic. As for the `Interlocked`, do you think that it can fetch fresher values from the memory than the `volatile`? Also I don't understand what's the advantage of the combination `CompareExchange`/`Exchange` over doing just a single direct `Exchange`. Both seem functionally the same to me, with the former having added overhead because of the possibility of two calls.

Comment: You would need the `CompareExchange` if the new value of `_threadSafeNullBool` was depending on its existing value. But in this case your just want to set its value, independently of what the current value is.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, if the variable is `volatile` still every thread caches it's value and `Interlocked` functions are providing way to get the latest value.
The `CompareExchange` calls in the setter are because if you are trying to set the same value, you don't want to do write always (unnecessary write access). So you are only reading the value and changing it if it's needed. There is always 1 read access and 1 write access (if the value really need to change). Although there are 2 comparisons.

Comment: If the `volatile` variables were cached by each thread, then the `volatile` keyword would be practically useless. So I don't think it's true. But I would agree that the semantics of the `Interlocked` class are simpler and more straightforward, so I am OK with that. On the other hand trying to prevent unnecessary writes by using the `CompareExchange`+`Exchange` combo seems like needless complexity and wasted effort. Have you done any benchmarks that show any performance improvements by doing so? Or you are just concerned about wearing unnecessarily the hardware components?