How to cause tearing on Nullable<long>?
If I run the below code in x86 (32-bit) mode (.NET Framework 4.7.2 on recent Windows 11 machine) then, as expected, it writes to the console (proving that the data read out is not one of the two values being written) due to tearing:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/variables.md#96-atomicity-of-variable-references
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#96-atomicity-of-variable-references
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151905/34092

So that is expected. And based on those references, as well as Lippert's comments at https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/, I expected Nullable<long> to also exhibit tearing.
And yet, well it doesn't (uncomment the code below to repro). Now of course, this is legal I am sure. The fact that they tell you something isn't safe doesn't mean it definitely won't work - it is perfectly valid for it to work. But I am curious as to why tearing isn't occurring...
Is there a way to cause tearing on Nullable<long> (with only a single writer)?
Bonus points if you can get the same result when running on 64-bit.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long bob = 0;
            //long? bob = 0;

            long small = 0;
            long large = long.MaxValue;


            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                do
                {
                    bob = small;
                    bob = large;
                } while (true);
            });

            for (long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue - 2; i++)
            {
                var value = bob;

                if (value != small && value != large)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("very bad");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


Note, bob small and large would all be promoted to class fields, to compile the lambda. Nullable<T> should be struct { bool, T}, T should be aligned to sizeof(T). Though the compiler is allowed to remove data races. Maybe you need to ensure the write operations are volatile, or the compiler might optimise something away?

@JeremyLakeman Well looks like you were on to something in terms of the promotion of class fields. Write that up (i.e. change the code sample to https://dotnetfiddle.net/auYmPH and I'll grant you the answer.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Memory-model.md "... Programs that do rely on observing data races shall use volatile accesses". If you don't use volatile, the compiler might optimise code in such a way that "data races" will be eliminated. eg eliminating multiple writes to the same memory, moving reads outside of loops so they only occur once. (it's the field that's volatile, which means you can't use a lambda capture and will need to move the variable to a field yourself).

But you can't use volatile with nullable?

@mjwills correct, "volatile" in C# only applies to variables that contain (1) things the same size as a pointer, such as a reference, intptr, and so on, and (2) things that are 32 bits or smaller, such as an enum that wraps a byte. Those things don't exhibit tearing.


Is there a way to cause tearing on Nullable?

Yes.
With this code (adapted from this answer) where we introduce repetitive races between three threads where we assign to a local variable (that will be promoted to a field from the compiler for the lambdas):

Thread 1 - assigns null (this sets hasValue=false, value=0)
Thread 2 - assigns 2 ( hasValue=true,value=2)
Thread 3 - assigns long.MaxValue. (..same as above)

This will illustrate three types of tears:

HasValue being false, but the Value inside not being 0.
HasValue being true, but the Value inside is 0.
HasValue being true, but the Value itself is torn, i.e. neither 0, 2 or long.MaxValue which will happen on 32bit only.

Code:
static void Main() {
    int tries = 2_000_000; // increase if you aren't getting any tears

    // Nullable<long> Layout 
    // bool hasValue - padded
    // long value 
    Console.WriteLine("Long MaxValue: " + long.MaxValue);
    Console.WriteLine("----");

    // Null Tear Type 1 - occurs both 32bit/64bit
    // l = null; // <<<false>>> 0
    // l = 2; // true <<<2>>>
    // l = long.MaxValue; // true <<long.MaxValue>>
    Func<long?, bool> nullTearType1 = x => x.HasValue == false &&
                                    x.GetValueOrDefault() != 0;

    // Null Tear Type 2 - occurs both on 32bit/64bit
    // l = null; // false <<<0>>>
    // l = 2; // <<<true>>> 2
    // l = long.MaxValue; // <<<true>>> long.MaxValue
    // note this is hardest to get on .NET Core due to the following needing to occur
    // thread 1: vmovdqu[rdx], xmm0 -> starts writing 0(false) in the first part of the struct
    // thread 2: mov byte ptr[rdx], 1 -> overrides false to true
    // thread 2: mov qword ptr[rdx + 8], 2 -> writes 2
    // thread 1: vmovdqu[rdx], xmm0 -> ends writing 0 to the second part overwriting 2
    // i.e. two mov instructions sneaking between one vmodqu
    Func<long?, bool> nullTearType2 = x => x.HasValue == true &&
                                    x.GetValueOrDefault() == 0;
                                    
    // Value Tear - occurs only on 32bit - long are not atomic there
    // l = null; // false <<0>>
    // l = 2; // <<<true>>> <<<2>>>
    // l = long.MaxValue; // <<<true>>> <<<long.MaxValue>>>
    Func<long?, bool> longTear = x => x.HasValue == true &&
                                    x.GetValueOrDefault() != 0 &&
                                    x.GetValueOrDefault() != 2 &&
                                    x.GetValueOrDefault() != long.MaxValue;


    long? l = 0; // will be captured as field cause of closures
    // shared variable for the threads
    
    var listTears = new List<long?>();
    Action<Barrier> actionAfterRaceCompletes = _ => {
        if (nullTearType1(l)) {
            listTears.Add(l);
        }
        if (nullTearType2(l)) {
            listTears.Add(l);
        }
        if (longTear(l)) {
            listTears.Add(l);
        }
        l = 0; // reset for next race
    };

    var barrier = new Barrier(3, actionAfterRaceCompletes);

    var t1 = new Thread(() => {
        for (int j = 0; j < tries; j++) {
            l = null;
            barrier.SignalAndWait();
        }
    });

    var t2 = new Thread(() => {
        for (int j = 0; j < tries; j++) {
            l = 2;
            barrier.SignalAndWait();
        }
    });

    var t3 = new Thread(() => {
        for (int j = 0; j < tries; j++) {
            l = long.MaxValue;
            barrier.SignalAndWait();
        }
    });


    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();

    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
    t3.Join();

    var countTears = listTears.Count;
    Console.WriteLine($"Struct tears: {countTears}");
    Console.WriteLine("-----");

    var nullTearType1Tears = listTears
        .Where(nullTearType1);

    var nullTearType2Tears = listTears
        .Where(nullTearType2);

    var valueTears = listTears
        .Where(longTear);


    Console.WriteLine("Null Tear Type 1: " + nullTearType1Tears.Count());
    foreach (var element in nullTearType1Tears.Distinct()) {
        Console.WriteLine(element.HasValue + " " + element.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----");

    Console.WriteLine("Null Tear Type 2: " + nullTearType2Tears.Count());
    foreach (var element in nullTearType2Tears.Distinct()) {
        Console.WriteLine(element.HasValue + " " + element.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----");

    Console.WriteLine("Value Tear: " + valueTears.Count());
    foreach (var element in valueTears.Distinct()) {
        Console.WriteLine(element.HasValue + " " + element.GetValueOrDefault());
    }

}

// possible results on 32bit
Long MaxValue: 9223372036854775807
----
Struct tears: 431
-----
Null Tear Type 1: 171
False 9223372036854775807
-----
Null Tear Type 2: 182
True 0
-----
Value Tear: 78
True 9223372032559808514
True 4294967295


so we could freely check the fields of the struct and bypass the .HasValue check in the .Value property getter which gets in our way. That is all unnecessary @IvanPetrov since Nullable.GetValueOrDefault() does the same (i.e. bypasses the HasValue check).

@mjwills thanks, will edit at some point when I also figure out why we don't get the other case, i.e. HasValue = true, Value = 0.

@mjwills yeah, my updated one too. I think it gets to do with the assembly instructions but cannot be too sure.

Any luck with tearing when null isn't involved?

@mjwills what do you mean? If we use different values, the hasValue field will be the same and we will just be updating the value portion which won't introduce "tearing" per se, just normal races. Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean.

The atomicity of the Value part occurs now, in practice, but it could change in future (e.g. if they changed the memory layout of the fields). See the StructLayout bit in my answer.

@mjwills actually, there is no atomicity for the Value on 32bit. I thought we were talking about struct tears, not long tears. Check my updated answer which tackles all cases (null and value tears).

Yep - for 32-bit I got tearing to occur with long? - search for running as 32-bit with a slight change to the original code on this page.

@mjwills glad that you figured how to simulate this with Task.Run. It would have been really something if packing something into a struct lifted laws of 32bit gravity.

@IvanPetrov's great answer got me thinking, resulting in this repro based on my original code.
I can get tearing to occur with a single writer and a concurrent read from Nullable<long> when running as 64-bit as long as one of the writes is the value null:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long large = long.MaxValue;

            long? bob = null;

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                long large2 = long.MaxValue;

                do
                {
                    bob = null;
                    bob = large2;
                } while (true);
            });


            for (long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue - 2; i++)
            {
                var value = bob;
                var value2 = value.GetValueOrDefault();

                if (value == large)
                {
                    // Fine
                }
                else if (value == null && value2 == 0)
                {
                    // Fine
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                    Console.WriteLine(value.HasValue);
                    Console.WriteLine(value.GetValueOrDefault());
                    Console.WriteLine(large);
                    Console.WriteLine("very bad");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

I am still unable to get it to tear if the two values being written are not null. This is likely explained by the fact that the default memory layout of a struct will properly align long (and other data types). And then, as per the docs those reads will be atomic. But given the docs explicitly do not promise that nullables are atomic, nothing stops them from changing the implementation of Nullable<T> in future. For example, if they switched to [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)] then tearing of the long value itself could occur. Example (uncomment the attribute to cause the issue):
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    //[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    struct MyUnalignedNullableStruct<T>
    {
        public bool HasValue;   // Offset: 0
        public T Value; // Offset: 1
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long> large = new MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long>() { HasValue = true, Value = long.MaxValue };
            MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long> small = new MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long>() { HasValue = true, Value = 0 };

            MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long> bob = small;

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long> large2 = new MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long>() { HasValue = true, Value = long.MaxValue };
                MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long> small2 = new MyUnalignedNullableStruct<long>() { HasValue = true, Value = 0 };

                do
                {
                    bob = small2;
                    bob = large2;
                } while (true);
            });


            for (long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue - 2; i++)
            {
                var value = bob;

                if (value.Value == long.MaxValue || value.Value == 0)
                {
                    // Fine
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(large.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("very bad");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

As such, given the docs don't commit to atomicity, I think my question is basically answered. In practice, with the current implementation, the long value of the Nullable<long> will never be subject to tearing if you set it to long values (and never null), but there is no guarantee that that will continue in the future.

sizeof(long) == 8 and on a 64bit platform, all aligned 64bit writes will be atomic.

Given that the HasValue field takes storage space (on top of the 64-bits for the long value), can we rely on the fact that the entirety of the long exists in a single aligned 64 bit space? Could it not, for example, have the HasValue at the start, then the long, then any necessary padding, such that the long is split over two 64-bit parts of memory? And if it doesn't do that, is that contractual? Or just an implementation detail?

I mean, I can't get it to occur (i.e. if it is a nullable long but I never set it to null it effectively doesn't tear) - but https://stackoverflow.com/a/33529054/34092 makes me think that might be good luck rather than a contract I can rely on.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Memory-model.md#alignment Though you probably want to read it all anyway.

Thanks @JeremyLakeman - updated the answer to incorporate that.

I can get tearing to occur with a single writer and a concurrent read from Nullable<long> when running as 32-bit with a slight change to the original code (thanks to @JeremyLakeman). I will remove this answer if he decides to post his own.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long small = 0;
            long large = long.MaxValue;

            //long bob = 0;
            long? bob = 0;


            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                long small2 = 0;
                long large2 = long.MaxValue;


                do
                {
                    bob = small2;
                    bob = large2;
                } while (true);
            });


            for (long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue - 2; i++)
            {
                var value = bob;

                if (value != small && value != large)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                    Console.WriteLine(value.GetValueOrDefault());
                    Console.WriteLine(small);
                    Console.WriteLine(large);
                    Console.WriteLine("very bad");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

The key change here, as suggested by @JeremyLakeman, was to not read small and large from within the Task.Run lambda.
